# Azure SQL: Adding from Blob Not Recognizing Storage

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to load data from a CSV file to a table in my Azure Database following the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-importing-data-from-a-file-in-azure-blob-storage, using the Managed Identity option. When I run the query, I receive this error:
`Failed to execute query. Error: Referenced external data source "adfst" not found.`

This is the name of the container I created within my storage account. I have also tried using my storage account, with the same error. Reviewing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15 does not provide any further insight as to what may be causing the issue. My storage account does not have public (anonymous) access configured.

I'm assuming that I'm missing a simple item that would resolve this issue, but I can't figure out what it is. My SQL query is below, modified to not include content that should not be required.

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '**************';
GO
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL msi_cred WITH IDENTITY = '***********************';
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE adfst
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/adfst'
          , CREDENTIAL= msi_cred
);
BULK INSERT [dbo].[Adventures]
FROM 'Startracker_scenarios.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'adfst');
```

Comment: Did you create `msi_cred` according to the [Shared Access Signature requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?i-create-an-external-data-source-for-bulk-operations-retrieving-data-from-azure-storage)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No, because I created a Managed Identity instead.

Comment: Are you sure managed identity is supported? The documentation says you need a SAS.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, from the first link I added: "Another way to access the storage account is via Managed Identity. To do this follow the Steps 1 thru 3 to configure SQL Database to access Storage via Managed Identity, after which you can implement code sample as below". The code I posted is based off the code sample mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Managed Identity to access Azure Blob storage when you run `BULK INSERT` command. You need to enable Managed Identity for the SQL server. Otherwise, you will get the error `Referenced external data source "***" not found`. Besides, you also need to assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the MSI. If you do not do that, you cannot access the CVS file storing in Azure blob

For example

1. Enable  Managed Identity for the SQL server

```
Connect-AzAccount

#Enable MSI for SQL Server
Set-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName your-database-server-resourceGroup -ServerName your-SQL-servername -AssignIdentity
```

2. Assign role via Azure Portal
   Under your storage account, navigate to **Access Control (IAM)**, and select **Add role** **assignment**. Assign **Storage Blob Data Contributor** RBAC role to the server  which you've registered with Azure Active Directory (AAD)

[image]

3. Test

   a. Data

   ```
   1,James,Smith,19750101
   2,Meggie,Smith,19790122
   3,Robert,Smith,20071101
   4,Alex,Smith,20040202
   ```

   b. script

```
CREATE TABLE CSVTest
(ID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(40),
LastName VARCHAR(40),
BirthDate SMALLDATETIME)
GO

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourStrongPassword1';
GO

--> Change to using Managed Identity instead of SAS key 
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL msi_cred WITH IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity';
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://jimtestdiag417.blob.core.windows.net/test'
          , CREDENTIAL= msi_cred 
);
GO
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'mydata.csv'
WITH (
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage');
GO

select * from CSVTest;
GO
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've done all of that; in fact, I just did it all again, and I'm still getting the same error.